# NameError: uninitialized constant Model - rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I'm trying to migrate a change to my Comments table with rails migration.  I've already made the migration and everything looks good but when I run `rake db:migrate` it sends back this error `NameError: uninitialized constant Model`. I can't see the problem? All the naming look right to me. Here is my migration file let me know if anything looks off or if you need more information. Thank you!

MIGRATION:

```
class AddColumnToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  add_column :comments, :fav_drink, :string
  add_column :comments, :visit_time, :string
 end
end
```

ERROR:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your Comment model?

Comment: i don't see any issue in your migration, post your model code. Also please confirm if you are able to start your server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've used rails generator to create your migration and this generator has probably create a migration file named: `201606xxxxxxxx_model.rb`.

If it's the case, rename you migration file as follow: `201606xxxxxxxx_add_column_to_comments.rb`